# Spring XD dist task fails when building from a branch

Tags: spring-xd

gradlew dist -xtest -xjavadoc -xsetupui

When dist from master, build succeeds.

When running from branch, it fails.I did push the branch to my remote, but I am not sure why the gradle task should know about remote branches. I could run successfully with -xpullDocs

Seems something to do with "wikiBranch" property.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
10:34:14.670 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:34:14.670 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
10:34:14.670 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Script '/Users/{$ID}/spring-xd/gradle/build-docs.gradle' line: 58
10:34:14.670 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:34:14.670 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
10:34:14.671 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':pullDocs'.
10:34:14.671 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Error while switching to branch: origin/jms-transport. Cause: Ref origin/{branch} can not be resolved
10:34:14.672 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:34:14.673 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
10:34:14.674 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':pullDocs'.
10:34:14.674 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
10:34:14.674 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
10:34:14.674 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
10:34:14.674 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
10:34:14.674 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
10:34:14.674 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
10:34:14.674 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
10:34:14.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
10:34:14.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
10:34:14.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
10:34:14.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
10:34:14.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
10:34:14.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-PwikiBranch=origin/master`

Answer (score 0):

At present, we maintain the documentation separately from the main sources. We found it initially helpful to use the GitHub wiki (with its editing capabilities) as the source for Spring XD's documentation. Github's wiki is a separate Git repo and cause *some complexities*.

With multiple active XD branches, we had to maintain multiple documentation branches as well.

Therefore, if you use a custom branch, you have to pass the **-PwikiBranch** parameter using Gradle, e.g.:

`./gradlew dist -PwikiBranch=origin/master`

For some more details, please also see: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/gradle/build-docs.gradle#L37